# Logback couldn't log asian characters correcly to files

Tags: java, encoding, logback

My Logback logs are displaying a lot of things like

é»„å˜‰çš“

in the log files whenever it encounters asian characters. It seems like the file is in unicode instead of UTF-8.

This is my Logback groovy config

```html
/*
 * Logback configuration in Groovy.
 * 
 * While this appears to be the Logback preference going forward you can still
 * use an XML configuration file by deleting this one and creating a 
 * logback.xml in its place.
 */

import java.nio.charset.Charset
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.*

def DEFAULT_PATTERN = "%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n"

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
 encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) { 
  pattern = DEFAULT_PATTERN 
  charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
 }
}

appender("FILE", RollingFileAppender) {
  file = "logs/stdout.log"
  append = true
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = DEFAULT_PATTERN
    charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
  }
  filter(ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter) {
    level = INFO
  }
  rollingPolicy(ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = "logs/stdout-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
    maxHistory = 10
    timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP) {
      maxFileSize = "1MB"
    }
  }
}

appender("ERROR", RollingFileAppender) {
  file = "logs/errors.log"
  append = true
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = DEFAULT_PATTERN
    charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
  }
  filter(ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter) {
    level = ERROR
  }
  rollingPolicy(ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = "logs/errors-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
    maxHistory = 10
    timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP) {
      maxFileSize = "1MB"
    }
  }
}

/* Make Spring less verbose. */
//logger("org.springframework", INFO)

/* Quieten Thymeleaf. */
//logger("org.thymeleaf", INFO)

/* Jetty can be really noisy on a shaded jar. */
//logger("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader", INFO)
//logger("org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.JarResource", INFO)

/* Quieten Jetty in general. */
//logger("org.eclipse", ERROR);

def appenders = []
appenders.add("STDOUT")
appenders.add("FILE")
appenders.add("ERROR")

root(INFO, appenders)
```

Also, when I started my JAR, I also specified -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.
I really have no clue here how to fix this.

Please let me know if you know what might be able to fix it.

Thank you so much

Comment: how are you viewing your logs

Comment: turns out it is the log viewer app that has the incorrect encoding setting, duh, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: i have posted an answer, appreciate if you can edit and add settings of log viewer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have already set **charset pattern to UTF-8** in logback properties/xml.

You should be looking at the tool from which you are viewing your logs. There need to be done some settings.

```
1. Notepad         :  By changing font to "Lucida Console"
2. Notepad++       :  By changing Encoding to "UTF-8"
3. Console         :  By changing font and codepage.
```